# Baking normal maps creates artefacts at the seams. How do you guys deal with them?

Tags: normal-map, multiresolution

We've sculpted some pants and then baked them using a multires mesh. Great results, however, I get artefacts at seams. Here's a picture:
[image: Bump mapping with seam artefacts]

The artefacts can be a little hard to see, since we've done our best to clean them up, but you can see that the colors coming from the left and the right, especially at the calf (lower red arrow), do not match. I've done as much research about this as possible and tried everything I could find.

Normal map is a 1024x1024 with no alpha, 32 bit float precision. Higher precision reduced the severity of artefacts. Changing color space did nothing.

In the bake menu, the only option is increasing the margin, which does nothing. I mean, it does increase the padding in the texture, but the seam remains.

After testing some stuff I've figured that it's because the edges (marked as yellow in the UV unwrap) are not aligned. If I apply Align Y to both of them, the seam almost disappears. I guess that if they were also scaled the same way, the seams would be gone. But that would require pretty much all islands to look like squares.

I am not sure that this makes much sense. Painting the meshes does not have those artefacts. Am I doing something wrong? This is a very common issue and yet I do not see any solutions that work for us. How do you guys deal with normal mapping seams? Is there like a workflow that bypasses that stuff? Or is this like a blender bug?